# How to Have NaCL at AWS Lambda Properly Working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda, nacl-cryptography

I am using [Pychromeless repo](https://github.com/21buttons/pychromeless) with success at AWS lambda.

Now I need to use NaCL dependency, to decrypt a string, but I am getting

`Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/lib/nacl/_sodium.abi3.so`

with a complement of

`invalid ELF header`

when running the function on AWS Lambda.

I know it is a problem specific related to AWS Lambda environment, because I can run the function on my Mac inside docker.

Here's my requirements.txt file

```
boto3==1.6.18
botocore==1.9.18
selenium==2.53.6
chromedriver-install==1.0.3
beautifulsoup4==4.6.1
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
editdistance==0.5.3
future==0.17.1
idna==2.7
python-telegram-bot==10.1.0
requests==2.19.1
soupsieve==1.7.3
urllib3==1.23
PyNaCl==1.3.0
```

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:python3.6
MAINTAINER tech@21buttons.com

USER root

ENV APP_DIR /var/task

WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY bin ./bin
COPY lib ./lib

RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR/lib
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t /var/task/lib
```

And the makefile:

```
clean:
    rm -rf build build.zip
    rm -rf __pycache__

fetch-dependencies:
    mkdir -p bin/

    # Get chromedriver
    curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
    unzip chromedriver.zip -d bin/

    # Get Headless-chrome
    curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-37/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip
    unzip headless-chromium.zip -d bin/

    # Clean
    rm headless-chromium.zip chromedriver.zip

docker-build:
    docker-compose build

docker-run:
    docker-compose run lambda src/lambda_function.lambda_handler


build-lambda-package: clean fetch-dependencies
    mkdir build
    cp -r src build/.
    cp -r bin build/.
    cp -r lib build/.
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t build/lib/.
    cd build; zip -9qr build.zip .
    cp build/build.zip .
    rm -rf build
```

Without the decryption part, the code works great. So the issue is 100% related to PyNaCl.

Any help on solving this?

Comment: So fast? `numpy/core/multiarray.so` and `/lib/nacl/_sodium.abi3.so` are two different things. The only similarity is the error thrown by lambda: `invalid ELF header`. Please, don't invalidate my question, man.

Comment: Well, I am using docker. So, I was expecting some useful tips/lines for my dockerfile. If I need to "spin up an ec2 instance and create virtualenv with the necessary dependencies", what would be the use of docker?

Comment: How you run your container?

Comment: Updating question with my makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to setup `PyNaCl` like so:

```
SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip3 install pynacl
```

that will force `PyNaCl` to use the version of libsodium provided by `AWS`

see [this](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/)

in the last version of `PyNaCl`is updated to `libsodium 1.0.16.` so maybe it is not compatible with `AWS`

so you may remove `PyNaCl` from `requirements.txt` and add this to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip3 install pynacl -t /var/task/lib
```

or maybe setup the `dockerfile` like this and keep `PyNaCl` in `requirements.txt`:

```
ARG SODIUM_INSTALL=system
```

Try also to setup sodium before installing PyNaCI:

`RUN wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.15.tar.gz \
&& tar xzf libsodium-1.0.15.tar.gz \
&& cd libsodium-1.0.15 \
&& ./configure \
&& make install`

Comment: Interesting. So where does this `SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip install pynacl` line go?

Comment: Done. Now the error has changed. AWS Lambda says: `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'nacl'`. I must say 2 things: 1) I have `import nacl.secret` and `import nacl.encoding` on my lambda function, 2) Everything worked OK running docker on my machine.

Comment: ah sorry you need to use pip3 like the other modules

Comment: All options worked fine running docker on my machine. None of the options worked on AWS Lambda: with `pynacl` on "requirements.txt" = `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/lib/nacl/_sodium.abi3.so: invalid ELF header`. Without it = `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'nacl'`. *dockerfile was set up like you said.

Comment: See the update , now I am out of ideas :) Please Post tue Solution if you find it

Comment: `/bin/sh: wget: command not found` Thanks for your help and time. I will try other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I did it. I had to build everything on an EC2 AMI Linux 2 instance.

amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20190823.1-x86_64-gp2 (ami-0a1f49a762473adbd)

After launching the instance, I use [this script](https://gist.github.com/PabTorre/12f514f97688072d6a598f00707d4db4) to install Python 3.6 (and pip) and to create and activate a virtual environment.

For the docker part, I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html), not without some troubles on the way (had to

`sudo yum install polkit`

and

`sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user`

and

reboot

and

`sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

and

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`).

But anyway, I manage to work with docker on the EC2 instance, building the zip file and uploading it to Lambda environment, where everything worked fine, as I expected.

I thought docker was an environment independent from the host, but I guess that is not the case.